# How can Google Apps Script to delete a specific sheet by name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In spreadsheet, I have a sheet named "Sheet1" which is a summary of all sheets I've created. I'm trying to delete a specific row from "Sheet1" and it's corresponding sheet by name. The "x" is a variable in the script, I can successfully remove row "5" from "Sheet1", but can not remove sheet "5" from worksheet.

```
function myFunction () {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AGDGqi7hh-vr96EuCCDl0PqdcVtwweoWpB2Lj0ajHR4/edit#gid=0");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");  
var x = 5; 
sheet.activate().deleteRow(x);  
var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(x);
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().deleteSheet(source);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't even need to activate the sheet before deleting it.

```
var source = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet"+x);// get the sheet object
ss.deleteSheet(source);// done !
```

Comment: The sheet name is "5", not "Sheet5". If I put getSheetByName(x), it not work.

Comment: sheetNames need to be of the string type, try x.toString()

Comment: How to make it string type?

Comment: just as I wrote above, see info here : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp

Comment: It works to delete the specific sheet by name. I make it string as  [ var  x = x.toString()  ]. I also follow your suggestion to use [ var source = ss.getActiveName(x) ;      ss.deleteSheet(source)   ] because my original code did not work. [    var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(x);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().deleteSheet(source);  ]